# android sinch audio and video calling in background

Tags: android

I implemented Sinch audio and video calling in my current app. When the app is in  the foreground everything is OK for the incoming call. But when I closed the app and tried to receive an incoming call, it does not show any incoming call. How to do audio and video Sinch calling when application is closed for incoming calls?

Comment: Please refer SINCH  document  https://www.sinch.com/docs/video/android/.. Take care of destroying the service of SINCH when app is closed

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use `Service` Class, and in service you have to write the code for incoming call and video.
For that you need to use `BroadcastReceiver` in service Class.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    // use this as an inner class like here or as a top-level class
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do something
        }

        // constructor
        public MyReceiver(){

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried using your answer but on Receive of broadcast receiver not called for sinch calling